# eXist-db: can't start webstart client on a closed port, reverse proxied via apache

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I am configuring an Apache HTTP server so it reverse proxies requests starting with /app/ to an eXist-db instance running in a Tomcat server, on port 8082. This port has been closed in the firewall and is inaccessible to the outer world. Following the [eXist documentation](http://exist-db.org/exist/production_web_proxying.xml#d58323e330), I have following rules in place in my httpd.conf file:

```
ProxyPass           /apps/  http://localhost:8082/
ProxyPassReverse    /apps/  http://localhost:8082/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /apps/ /
```

All goes well for requests to e.g. 'http://mydomain/apps/exist/index.xml'. Yet, the webstart client (accessible at 'http://localhost:8082/exist/webstart/exist.jnlp' on the web server) doesn't work behind the proxy. While 'http://mydomain/apps/exist/webstart/exist.jnlp' does generate a valid exist.jnlp file, that file can't be executed. The reason seems quite obvious: apparently, the eXist-db instance generating the exist.jnlp file only sees the proxied request as: 'http://localhost:8082/exist/webstart/exist.jnlp'. Yet, since the exist.jnlp file is executed on the client, that reference is meaningless (unless the client computer happens to have an eXist-db instance running on that port). Executing the exist.jnlp file hence fails with a 'connection refused' error.

Yet, there's no problem at all connecting a local eXist-db Java client to the proxied eXist instance with the URL xmldb:exist://mydomain/apps/exist/xmlrpc. The problem lies in *generating* the webstart exist.jnlp file, which seems to need access to a publicly accessible URL. However, opening port 8082 and replacing the Proxy references to 'http://localhost:8082' with 'http://mydomain:8082' IMO rather destroys the point of reverse proxying.

Do others have had success reverse proxying eXist-db on a closed port behind Apache? Are there perhaps some Proxy configuration settings I have overlooked (I'm no expert at all) that can make eXist see the original request instead of the proxied one?

Kind regards,

Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `ProxyPreserveHost On`, which sends the same Host: header it received to the back-end server.  More info [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kyle! This works when all requests are proxied ('/' instead of '/apps/') in the Proxy rules. Yet, when I try to proxy requests for http://mydomain/apps/exist/webstart.jnlp to http://localhost:8082/exist/webstart.jnlp using above mod_proxy rules, with the addition of "ProxyPreserveHost On", it still fails. Apparently, the request then ends up with http://mydomain/exist/webstart/exist.jnlp, instead of http://mydomain/apps/exist/webstart/exist.jnlp. The same pattern occurs with eXist-internal rewrites, where the /apps/ part is omitted from the final URL. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Well, that's because the user is requesting /exist/webstart/..., so I'm not sure how you'd modify the Host: header on the way through.

Comment: Yes, but with 'ProxyPreserveHost off', internal redirection by the eXist-db app **does** work: http://mydomain/apps/exist/eXide/ properly redirects to http://mydomain/apps/exist/eXide/index.html. With 'ProxyPreserveHost on', the same request suddenly redirects to http://mydomain/exist/eXide/index.html. The difference seems frustratingly subtle...